# How to display CKEditor generate code properly?

Tags: ckeditor

When I edit the content in CKeditor, it looks well. but when I display the data on html page. the layout are reset by other css file. How to avoid this? Is it possible to disable show the content in CKeditor without toolbar?

Comment: Without Toolbar How will the user edit the text?

Comment: I mean only display the save content from database. @Sukrit Gupta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content.css solve my problem. Add the style to content.css .

Answer (score 0):

ck editor is highly customizable. Go to your CKEditor Directory ckeditor\samples\index.html

Open this file

Click on ToolBar Configurator Button on top right Corner.

Switch to advanced mode. At top right corner there is a switch, toggle it to advanced mode.

Then build your toolbar.

Now click on 'Get ToolBar Config' Button.

Select and Copy the Configuration and Paste it into foll file:

ckeditor/config.js

For CSS issue: Try loading and calling the replace function at end of your html Page.